# Why CTOR is not called N times when I create a vector of N objects?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, stl

[Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/945a3858f52e92a1) the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Voice
{
public:
    Voice(int value) {
        std::cout << "ctor: " << value << std::endl;
    }
    ~Voice() {
        std::cout << "delete" << std::endl;
    }

private:
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Voice> mVoices;
    mVoices = std::vector<Voice>(10, Voice(999));
}
```

Why is the constructor only called 1 time if I create 10 different objects?

Comment: Whenever tracking construction and destruction calls do not forget to decorate your copy and move constructors.

Comment: You're only creating one instance using `Voice()` the rest are copies, using the compiler generated copy constructor.

Comment: As @George says, it copies the other instances from the one that is constructed.  See constructor set (2) here:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: So what if I want 10 distinct element within the vector? For example in the real example I create a new object with pointer on each object.

Comment: @paizza Define an appropiate copy constructor. Or add them one by one with `emplace_back()` inside a for-loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use

```
std::vector<Voice>(10, Voice(999))
```

Your not telling the compiler to make 10 `Voice`s and put them into the vector.  What you tell it is make one `Voice` (`Voice(999)`) and then copy that object into each element in the vector.

This means that you have 1 constructor call and 10 calls to the copy constructor of the class.  Since the class does not have a copy constructor the compiler provides one but it does not print anything.  If you want to see these copies being made you need to write you own like

```
Voice(const Voice& rhs)
{
    std::cout << "copy " << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The class has a compiler-generated copy constructor that hasn't been instrumented.

Comment: What do you mean? `Voice(int value)`? Not sure what you are talking about :(

Comment: @paizza Read about [copy constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

Comment: This answer is technically correct but unclear to those with the knowledge level of the OP, and furthermore does not actually explain why the copy constructor is relevant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - yes, obviously, and intentionally. People learn by exploring.

Answer (score 3):

Like Pete already said, C++ used your compiler generated copy constructor:
Add this to your class:

```
Voice(const Voice& rhs)
{
    std::cout << "copy " << std::endl;
}
```

Modified your class, i hope it is clearer, now:

```
class Voice
{
public:
    Voice(int value)
     :m_value(value)
    {
        std::cout << "ctor: " << m_value << std::endl;

    }
    Voice(const Voice& rhs)
        :m_value(rhs.m_value)
    {
        std::cout << "copy " << m_value << std::endl;
    }

    ~Voice() {
        std::cout << "delete " << m_value << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int m_value;
};
```

Comment: But I'm passing an int value :O

Comment: @paizza Yes, but that's only *one* of them. The rest of the objects are created by the vector using the copy ctor of the one you created with an int.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of `std::vector` you're calling is this:

```
explicit vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

which "constructs the container with `count` copies of elements with value `value`". ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector))

So the elements in your vector are **copies** of `Voice(999)`. `Voice(999)` is not called to initialize each element separately.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Pete's answer, its better to follow 'The rule of three' : [Rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

> If a class requires a user-defined destructor, a user-defined copy
>   constructor, or a user-defined copy assignment operator, it almost
>   certainly requires all three.